# How to pass GAID (Google Advertising ID) into Google Search request

Tags: google-chrome, security, reverse-engineering, google-ads-api

I want to programmatically search google for certain keywords and associate these requests with provided GAID (Google Advertising ID). So I can influence the advertising that Google shows me.

But when analyzing request body, I can't find cookie/header/get parameter that is responsible for passing GAID in the open form.

I made two identical requests with only difference that I did reset my GAID between requests, and found out that only some cookies became different in the request: `UULE`, `SIDCC`, `__Secure-1PSIDCC`, `__Secure-3PSIDCC`, `DV`

https://www.diffchecker.com/dflg2pYN/

They seem to be encrypted. Can somebody point me on what is exact cookie responsible for GAID, how to generate or change it?